# How to go down this table row wise and access selected attributes using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using webscraping, I am reading data from a table row wise. The html structure is shown below. Each row has a few columns (the highlighted ones) out of which I need to extract data. I have selected rows using:

```
for i in soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'resultRow'}):
```

so each item (i) in list is showing a whole row. Now I want to access information inside highlighted tags. If I do print(i.td), it prints only the next td tag. How can I access tags inside and their attributes?
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be pretty much the same as you did to find rows.

```
for col in i.find_all('td'):
    if 'class' in td:
        print(td['class'])
    if 'ng-repeat' in td:
        print(td['ng-repeat'])
```